# PHP MYSQL: Correct Code to Increment a views column every time a page is loaded in the browser

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I am trying to create a "views" system on my books website.

I have the following tables with the following columns:

```
Books
-bookid
-bookname
-authorid
-views
```

my webpage is set up to display a book based on the `$_GET['bookid']` variable and I want to add 1 (increment the `views` column by one for that particular book)

I tried using the following code but it didn't update my table:

```
<?php $sql = "UPDATE `books` \n" . "SET views = views+1 WHERE" . $_GET['bookid'] .= "bookid"; ?>
```

**ALSO: I used dreamweaver to run the recordset query) so maybe something is different.**

Please Help!

**Sidenote: Can you please recommend a good book/video or written tutorial to learn php and mysql for absolute beginners like my self!**

Comment: have you considered using something like google analytics?

Comment: Check out the Lynda training videos. Great way to get your feet wet.

Comment: [Please make it stop...](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is important: **don't include $_GET paramaters directly in your SQL query.**

This makes your website vulnerable to an SQL Injection attack. Sanatise your inputs by using:

```
$book_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['book_id']); // If it is a string
$book_id = intval($_GET['book_id']); // It it is an integer

// Assuming it is an integer
$sql = "UPDATE books SET views = views+1 WHERE bookid = $book_id";
```

You obviously need to execute that query, are you doing that?

```
$user="username";
$password="password";
$database="database";
mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();
```

EDIT:
Also, just a tip, since you're using `$_GET` you should be executing something like `yourscript.php?book_id=12345`, is that what you're doing?

Comment: that's your problem then. use books.php?book_id=1 instead of ?=1

Answer (score 1):

you've already found some of the best ways to learn PHP: writing code and coming here when you don't know further :) (don't have a real good tutorial on my hands beyond that ;)
As for your question:

- check the value of `$_GET['bookid']`
- check the value of `$sql`
- if all looks as intended, run the query directly

oh wait.
you're not actually executing the sql in your code, just generating a string with the query. you need to open a connection etc, or are you doing that and leaving it out here?

Comment: +1. As obvious that is hard to find. Also: ... and when connection will be opened, put `spaces` between where and bookid code.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks slightly off.  Try this:
`$sql = 'UPDATE books SET views = views+1 WHERE bookid = ' . intval($_GET['book_id']);`

Comment: :( it didn't work! Maybe I'm doing something else wrong! BTW I used dreamweaver to generator the query! because I know nothing about mysql.

Comment: Have you tried running the query in MySQL directly (`UPDATE books SET views = views+1 WHERE bookid = 1;`)?  If it works then I'd suggest taking a look at the value you're getting from `$_GET['book_id']`.